# I need to add required form fields to my contact form but not sure about how to do it?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am very new to php and so I need some help adding required fields to my contact form. I want to display a nice "error" message telling the viewer to input something into the required field.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $to = "benlevygraphics@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Ben, you have been contacted...";
            $body = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nWebsite: " . $_POST['web'] . "\n" . "\nFavorite Piece of work: " . $_POST['favwork'] . "\n" . "\nMessage: " . $_POST['message'];

            if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

            echo("<p class=contactformsent>".$_POST['name'].", your information was received. For your records an email has also been sent to you!</p>");

            }
            else{
               echo("<p class=contactformnotsent>".$_POST['name'].", Message delivery failed...</p>");
            }
       }

               if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $headers = "From: benlevygraphics@gmail.com" ;
            $subject = "You contacted benlevywebdesign";
            $body =  $_POST['name'].",  Thank you for taking a look at my portfolio and contacting me.  I have received your contact information/message and I will get back to you as soon as I can!" . "\n" . "\nFor your records I have:" . "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nWebsite: " . $_POST['web'] . "\n" . "\nFavorite Piece of work: " . $_POST['favwork'] . "\n" . "\nMessage: " . $_POST['message'];

            if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
            }
       }

?>
```

and here is the html code:

```
<?php include("contactform.php"); ?>

<form id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<fieldset>
            <p class="form">Name*
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30"/>
            </p>
            <p class="form">Email*
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
            </p>...(the rest of the form html code here)
```

and then the last lines:

```
 <p class="submit"><button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button></p>

    </form>
```

Comment: when while typing or after submitted  ?

Comment: Thats a good point! When the viewer clicks on submit and before it sends the data!

Comment: it mean you want to perform this on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general, you should be escaping any input from the browser to prevent bad things from happening if you're going to ever display it in a browser or save it to a database.**

Before the the following line:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
```

You would need to add some validation to the form like so:

```
$errors = array();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Please enter your name!';
}

if (empty($email)) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Please enter your e-mail!';
}
```

Then change your email line to something like:

```
if(!count($errors) && mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
```

Then instead of:

```
echo("<p class=contactformnotsent>".$_POST['name'].", Message delivery failed...</p>");
```

You could add an extra error like so if mail fails:

```
$errors['sendmail'] = 'Unable to send the e-mail!';
```

Additionally, you would just look for any errors on the form itself and loop through them at the top or under each input:

```
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    print $error."<br />\n";
}
```

Of course, this is just a start; you should definitely do some additional checks. For example, checking minimum length on name, stripping it of weird characters maybe and so on.

**UPDATE**

Ben, based on your comments, it seems like you want to do validation before the POST even happens. If this is the case, I'd recommend doing some basic jQuery validation.

Here's a page on [Basic jQuery Validation](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/basic-jquery-validation-form/) with an example.

Is that more what you're getting at?

Additionally, if you want the page to return to your form after you submit the comment, make sure your form URL has the target tag to your form like so:

```
<a name="comments_form" />
<form id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>#comments_form" method="POST">
```

Comment: How would I change the last part to check for errors? I think I understood everything else. Trying it out now, Thanks!

Comment: i think user is confused ,he wants to check before send data to server so it must be client side and validation see the comment below the question

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I think I want!

Comment: This way works for me except it doesn't keep whats in the form fields when the viewer clicks the button if there are errors?

Comment: @tdlm
http://benlevywebdesign.com If you look at my site and notice the form is at the bottom and when you click submit it sends and shows the confirmation or error message but it goes back to the top of the page and you don't know that it is there unless you scroll back down. How can I get it to submit and go back to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @benlevywebdesign I updated my answer based on your comments here. Let me know whether that helps!

Comment: And yes it does work. Thank you so much you just saved me from hours of searching again on the web for an answer that might not have worked! Thank you!

Comment: @tdlm last question, how do I get it to remember what was put in the form if I don't go the jQuery Validation route. so if you click on http://benlevywebdesign.com/#myAnchor7 and just fill out your name and then click send it refreshes with errors saying fill out your email and message but the name space is blank again. someone smart would fill it out again but it would be nice to have it not go away on refresh. does that make sense?

Comment: @benlevywebdesign, if you have it validate using jQuery, then the text values should not disappear. If you go with PHP POST validation, however, you'd just have to echo the variables into the input values like so:

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="<?php echo isset($name) ? $name : ""; ?>" />

Comment: @tdlm I don't know how to go about using the jQuery validation just yet because my form is php and the examples I have seen don't have php. Where would I put the lines of code for the post validation method? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @tdlm If I go the jQuery validation route I don't need the other lines of code for the php that you helped me with do I?

Comment: @benlevywebdesign, if you want to go the PHP way, here is sample working form.php (http://pastebin.com/YQVmkWsi) and here is contactform.php (http://pastebin.com/4rHDrtVi). I tested these on my local and they display errors right above the form as intended. However, if you do use jQuery validation you would not need the other lines of code, no. If you did that, the person would stay looking at the form while errors appeared. How you implement it is really up to you. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17028/discussion-between-benlevywebdesign-and-tdlm)

Answer (score 0):

At the Servers side you can just check for:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) { } // only send the mail if this is true.
```

There are also many client side solutions. You could also write your own using Javascript.
You will have to still include the checks on the server-side tho since "client-side security does not work".. The user could just disable Javascript and submit the form without the checks running.

Here is an example for a JS library that does form validation:

http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/

I found it by googling for `javascript form validation`

Comment: i think user is confused ,he wants to check before send data to server so it must be client side and validation see the comment below the question

Comment: As i stated in my comment, using only client side validation does not guarantee validation. The user cannot be forced to run a client-side script.

Comment: i know that client side is just only for user friendly the server side is must and more important

Comment: so if you want validation that means: you NEED server-side validation and you CAN add client side validation.

Comment: @Gung Foo http://benlevywebdesign.com/ If you look at my site and notice the form is at the bottom and when you click submit it sends and shows the confirmation or error message but it goes back to the top of the page and you don't know that it is there unless you scroll back down. How can I get it to submit and go back to the bottom of the page?

Comment: use a page anchor in the action of the form. http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm or look at the jquery scrollto plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo